# JSON-LD for event not needing tickets/performers

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm currently developing a page for an upcoming unicycling competition where teams from all over the country attend and the entry is completely free for everyone.

I tried to support my SEO by inserting structured data as JSON-LD, but the Google Search Console and the structured data testing tool complain about not having offers and a performer. Those are "Warnings".

Is it save to ignore "Warnings" or should I fill that data in somehow and if yes how?

My current data (real data replaced):

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "SportsEvent",
  "name": "Competition",
  "description": "Some Fine Descriptiont",
  "image": "https://url.de/image.jpg",
  "startDate": "startDate",
  "endDate": "EndDate",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "Arena",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "Street",
      "addressLocality": "City", 
      "postalCode": "12345",
      "addressCountry": "DE"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Structured Data Testing Tool will present two kinds of heads-up to you in testing: errors and warnings. Errors should be taken seriously and fixed, if possible, because often it means you've got incorrect format or are missing a piece of important identifying information. Warnings, on the other hand, are just recommendations; they should be fixed only if it makes sense to do so, which in your case it does not.

The warning itself reads: "The offers field is recommended. Please provide a value if available." The "recommended" and "if available" parts tell you that Google would like to see these if possible, but will work with what you give it if not.

Comment: Thanks, I was just cautious, because in the search console I got a message that said something like "due to problems not all search result features might be available to you" and the only problems were my structured data warnings.
(The problemtext isn't verbatim, because I'm german and got a german message)

Comment: @Snapstromegon If the only problem is the structured data warnings, the features they might have in mind may be the offer, performer, and other actions associated with those key:value pairs. Unfortunately, having those keys paired with empty string values doesn't make the warnings go away, but feel free to ignore them either way.